How to mock an angular class with signals?
I've an angular web app. I'm trying to test some services, that have other services as depenency.
I need to mock those others services to test my service.
I'm using Jest+auto-jest-spies to mock my classes, but I'm open to other suggestions.
Here is an example of class that I'm trying to mock(a store made with signalstory) :
import { computed, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ImmutableStore, useDevtools } from 'signalstory';
import { AccountStateModel } from './account-state.model';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AccountStore extends ImmutableStore<AccountStateModel> {
  constructor() {
    super({
      plugins: [useDevtools()],
      initialState: {
        isInitialized: false,
        email: null,
        accessToken: null,
        name: null,
        tokenExpiration: null,
        userId: null,
        permissions: null,
      },
    });
  }

  //Queries
  public get isLoggedIn() {
    return computed(() => !!this.state().userId);
  }
  public get userInfo() {
    return this.state;
  }

  // Commands
  //...
}

I'm trying to mock it like this:
describe('PermissionGuard', () => {
  let storeMock!: Spy<AccountStore>;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: AccountStore, useValue: createSpyFromClass(AccountStore, { gettersToSpyOn: ['isLoggedIn'] }) },
        PermissionGuard,
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
    storeMock = TestBed.inject<any>(AccountStore);
  });

it('should test the user access', async () => {
  //Arrange
  storeMock.isLoggedIn.mockReturnValue(false);

  //Act
  //...

  //Assert
  //...

  });
});

But the isLoggedIn is not recognized as a getter, I guess because it's a getter of a "function"(signal).
So what can I do to mock this class? I also want to make sure a signal has been accessed.

Essentially, the problem is that the getter function returns a signal, which is by itself a function. To keep all the characteristics of the signal intact, you could do something like this instead:

describe('PermissionGuard', () => {
  let storeMock: Spy<AccountStore>;
  let permissionGuard: PermissionGuard;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: AccountStore,
          useValue: createSpyFromClass(AccountStore, {
            methodsToSpyOn: ['isLoggedIn'],
          }),
        },
        PermissionGuard,
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
    storeMock = TestBed.inject(AccountStore) as Spy<AccountStore>;
    permissionGuard = TestBed.inject(PermissionGuard);
  });

  it('should test the user access', () => {
    //Arrange
    storeMock.isLoggedIn.mockImplementation(signal(true));

    //Act
    const result = permissionGuard.isValid();

    //Assert
    expect(result).toBe(true);
    expect(storeMock.isLoggedIn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(storeMock.isLoggedIn).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
  });
});


Assuming here that PermissionGuard is defined like

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PermissionGuard {
  constructor(private readonly account: AccountStore) {}

  isValid() {
    return this.account.isLoggedIn();
  }
}



Thanks I came to the same conclusion!

If you need to mock a service with signals in Angular and don’t have direct access to the set method, you can mock the whole service and return fixed values for the signal. Here’s a simple way to do it!
Let’s say MyService looks like this:
import { Injectable, signal } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService {
  mySignal = signal<number>(0);
}

And AnotherService depends on it:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './my-service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AnotherService {
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

  someMethodUsingSignal() {
    return this.myService.mySignal();
  }
}

Solution:
To mock MyService and return a fixed signal value in your tests, you can do something like this:
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AnotherService } from './another-service';
import { MyService } from './my-service';

describe('AnotherService', () => {
  let anotherService: AnotherService;
  let myServiceMock: jasmine.SpyObj<MyService>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const mockMyService = jasmine.createSpyObj('MyService', [], { mySignal: signal(10) });

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        AnotherService,
        { provide: MyService, useValue: mockMyService }
      ]
    });

    anotherService = TestBed.inject(AnotherService);
    myServiceMock = TestBed.inject(MyService) as jasmine.SpyObj<MyService>;
  });

  it('should use the mocked signal', () => {
    expect(anotherService.someMethodUsingSignal()).toBe(10);
  });
});

What’s happening here:
We're mocking MyService using jasmine.createSpyObj, and we give it a fixed signal value (signal(10)).
This way, when AnotherService calls someMethodUsingSignal(), it gets the value 10 from the mocked signal.
Super simple, right? If you also have a computed signal, you can mock it in the same way by returning a predefined value.
I hope this helps! Feel free to ask if you need any more details or tweaks. 

I'm not sure to understand: the signal is in another service(which has to be totally mocked). I don't have access to the "Set" of the from the exterior of my other service.
Also I've computed signal for which I need to be able to return a fixed value in the mocked service.
